# HTML5 Canvas Event Listeners and JavaScript - addEventListener("click")

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, closures, addeventlistener

Is there anyway to select a particular instantiated object of a HTML5 Canvas ("this" pointer) after a mouse click from inside that particular canvas?  Keep in mind that "Canvas" method I have shown is a non-standard function that I made up.

```
function Canvas(element) {
    this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.canvas.id = "display";
    var style = {"width" : "500",
                "height" : "500"};
    for(var index in style) {
        this.canvas[index] = style[index];
    }
    element == undefined ? document.body.appendChild(this.canvas) : element.appendChild(this.canvas);
    this.canvas.addEventListener("click", this.click, false);
}
```

then in a prototyped function I have...

```
Canvas.prototype.click = function(e) {
        this.mouse = [e.clientX, e.clientY];
        return this.of(this.mouse);
    }
```

Error:
this.of(this.mouse) doesn't exist however I have a prototype for this function (later on) in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you set the onclick handler:

```
this.canvas.addEventListener("click", this.click, false);
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

When you add an event listener, you pass the reference, in memory, of the handler. The context of that function (*this* pointer) is not bounded. So the *this* pointer in your case will be the canvas element. That's why you've got the following error:

> Object #< HTMLCanvasElement > has no method 'of'

To solve the problem you can use the bind function, introduced in Javascript 1.8.5, to bind the context. [(Function.prototype.bind reference)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
this.canvas.addEventListener("click", this.click.bind(this), false);
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcarv/wT8Qq/).

Comment: Yeah, Canvas.prototype.click(e){} binds to the original instantiated this object and also calls the click function with e.clientX & e.clientY.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, but try moving the definition for of() before that of click(). The order of functions is not always significant in JS, but I think it may be for prototypes. I may be wrong (I haven't checked) but it will only take a moment to test.

Comment: It didn't change anything.